# Epsilon-Natural number proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

I was able to fully grasp the Epsilon-delta proof but with the Epsilon-Natural number limit proof for sequence, I'm facing some confusion as regards the "idea".

So by the definition of Epsilon-Natural number limit proof:

For each Epsilon greater than zero, there is an n greater or equal to N such that 
|x_n - L| < epsilon.

If someone could explain to me the significance of this N and it's relation to the proof, that would be great!

Comment: Basically, if you go far enough out in your sequence, all of the values from that point on get really close to $c$

Comment: The formal language would be that there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that, whenever $n\ge N$, $|x_n-c|<\epsilon$

Comment: You are right. I was careless not to have included that.

Comment: @Brent:  good explanation, but it would be better to use OP's $L$ instead of $c$

Comment: This is a trivial and, possibly, very silly question but I can't see why the condition n >= N in the Natural number set is a sufficient condition.